# Pyodbc connection to Azure Synapse fails

Tags: odbc, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to connect to an azure synapse db from a centos box.

I get

```
"Unable to set SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING attribute"
```

right from the pyodbc.connect() method.
I did try to set pyodbc.pooling = False, before trying to get the connection, but then I get

```
"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 2: invalid start byte"
```

which is weird since I am not executing any query, just pyodbc.connect(...)

I also tried to set odbc trace but I get nothing in the log...

Here's my env:

```
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 
Python: Python 3.7.4
Pyodbc: Version: 4.0.30
ODBC: unixODBC 2.3.7

odbcinst.ini:
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.6.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

Is there a way to troubleshoot ?
Forgot to mention that I get the same message if I use the wrong driver name, or any of the other connection params.

thank you in advance

Comment: If you continue to struggle with this you may want to ask over on [GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/).

Comment: Thanks Gord, I will...

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/847

Comment: Hi @mihai, is the error solved now? Do you need post an answer here?

Comment: problem was solved, pls see here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/847#issuecomment-733087938

Comment: @mihai Congratulations! I just post this link as the answer. Hope you can accept it as answer. Others can see it and this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We are glad to hear that the error is solved.

For details, please see the GitHub here:
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/847#issuecomment-733087938